# React get styled component based on condition

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to change my project to exclusive styled-component use. I have something like this in

```
 <div className={isGrid ? "card-grid" : "card-list"}>
```

which my div get the card-grid or card-list className based on a condition. How will I implement this with styled-component and no css files? 
Also I need to the className to be always card-grid below 600px (@media)

Answer (score 0):

In styled-components you can use `${prop => prop.isGrid}` to render that logic. For the media query you can use a regular one in styled-components as well.

Comment: a bit more details about this?

Comment: Just as in regular React you can pass props to your styled-components and use the with the syntax I showed above. Here is an example from their docs.
https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props

Comment: ok lets say i have this in my styled component "flex-direction: ${props => props.isGrid ? 'column' : 'row'};" , how I will check the condition if isGrid == true and pass it as a prop on my Component?

Comment: You would send the prop from your React component. You either have your styled-component in a separate file or in the same as the React component, doesn't really matter. The styled-component will probably wrap your React component or be a child of it. This can look like:
https://jsfiddle.net/gydkmze9/

Tried to paste the snippet here but didn't work well.